# An array X[n] stores names only.Write an algorithm to insert or delete an ITEM in the array

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, data-structures

An array X[n] stores names only. The first position of the array does not store a name rather it stores the number of available free spaces in the array.Write an algorithm to insert or delete an ITEM in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert something in an array in say `pth` position, then all the elements from i upto last element should move to the next position (this will make the size increment). And put the desired element in pth position.

```
//you want to insert x in the pth position of A[n]
int temp = x; 
for(int i=p; i<n; i++) {
    swap(temp, A[i]);
}
A[n++] = temp;
```

Similarly, to delete in pth position just grab the next item to previous position and decrement size:

```
for(int i=p+1; i<n; i++) {
    A[i-1] = A[i];
}
n--;
```